# Efficient way to add items of a multidimensional array to have int values of grouped true values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So I have this array that is generated based on a user inputted number and randomly assigns true and false for each value.

```
array [
   [true, false, false, true, true],
   [false, false, false, false, true],
   [true, true, true, false, false],
   [false, true, true, false, true],
   [true, false, true, true, true]
]
```

I want to display numbers like in the picross games with this array.
for example:

```
array [
         1
         1                   1     2
         1      2     3      1     2
   1 2 [true, false, false, true, true],
     1 [false, false, false, false, true],
     3 [true, true, true, false, false],
   2 1 [false, true, true, false, true],
   1 3 [true, false, true, true, true]
]
```

I have attempted a good few solutions that doesn't really get the job done:

```
for(let i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
    array[i].forEach(element => {
        if(element == true) {
          readInt++
        } else {
          readInt = 0;
          readString += readInt + " ";
        }
    });
  }
  document.getElementById("hint1").innerHTML = readString;
```

I'm just wondering if there may be an easier way of achieving this?

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output is meant to be. and how you achieve it.

Comment: @Andy it's asking about implementing a game/puzzle; check out http://picross.net/ - question kind of makes sense if you know the game

Comment: @OP -- `I have attempted a good few solutions that doesn't really get the job done. I'm just wondering if there may be an easier way of achieving this?` What is the question here? Your code doesn't work or it does and you want a more elegant solution?

Comment: I had a solution but it was like 300 lines. I want to avoid such a long solution. I'll post my old solution when I get home